# How to calculate response time in Django

Tags: python, django

How do I calculate the response time from the moment where the user input the search criteria until the relevant information are loaded/displayed onto the portal?

Comment: start time(date time , put  this in first line of code) - end time(date time, put this in last line of code )

Comment: Have a look at [django debug toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#getting-the-code) as well if you want more robust debugging on different aspects of your django application.

Answer (score 17):

Since Django 1.10 this works differently now.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/

The new style would be as follows:

```
import time


class StatsMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        start_time = time.time()

        response = self.get_response(request)

        duration = time.time() - start_time

        # Add the header. Or do other things, my use case is to send a monitoring metric
        response["X-Page-Generation-Duration-ms"] = int(duration * 1000)
        return response
```

No need to store the start time on the request object and retrieve because it all happens in the same method.

It can also be done in a simple function style instead of a class:

```
import time


def stats_middleware(get_response):

    def middleware(request):
        start_time = time.time()

        response = get_response(request)

        duration = time.time() - start_time

        response["X-Page-Generation-Duration-ms"] = int(duration * 1000)
        return response

    return middleware
```

Answer (score 13):

Django is a python framework for backend operations. It's purpose is to process http requests, hence your question "from the moment where the user input the search criteria until the relevant information are loaded/displayed" is very vague in this context. Your question suggests you are looking at some interactive Javascript/Ajax based frontend?

If you are curious about render times for individual http requests, you may approach this with a custom middleware, something along these lines:

```
class StatsMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        "Start time at request coming in"
        request.start_time = time.time()

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        "End of request, take time"
        total = time.time() - request.start_time

        # Add the header.
        response["X-total-time"] = int(total * 1000)
        return response
```

Then, add this middleware in the corresponding Django `settings.py` section:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  ...
  'app.stats.StatsMiddleware',
  ...
)
```

The time it took to produce the response will be added to a custom http header "X-total-time". Note this will involve all rendering, calculation, 3rd party system and DB ops.

Comment: I have created a file called stats.py in my app folder and was executed it without error. May I know how to display this duration onto the webpage or somewhere I can gather such duration? Please advise. Tq.

Comment: when added to the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, in `settings.py`, results should show per request in the responses 'X-total-time' header.

Should you prefer to show the result somewhere on the page, you should leverage the template system. However, that approach will likely leave out rendering time in measurements.

To see the response header, the web console in, i.e. Firefox, should be sufficient.

Comment: **Important Note:** It should be installed as the first middleware in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in order to record the maximum duration.

Comment: use MiddlewareMixin instead of object

Answer (score 2):

Here’s the class that does the entire thing

```
import time


class StatsMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        "Store the start time when the request comes in."
        request.start_time = time.time()

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        "Calculate and output the page generation duration"
        # Get the start time from the request and calculate how long
        # the response took.
        duration = time.time() - request.start_time

        # Add the header.
        response["X-Page-Generation-Duration-ms"] = int(duration * 1000)
        return response
```

That’s all there’s to it. Just store the time when the request comes in, and retrieve it later.

To install the middleware above, just add it to your settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'project.stats_middleware.StatsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

Comment: How is your answer different from @Andreas?

Comment: actually I was writing and when I post then I saw that he has already posted solution.

Comment: Thanks. May I know where do I add the class? view.py?

Comment: put it in a file called something like stats_middleware.py

Comment: I have created a file called stats_middleware.py in my app folder and was executed it without error. May I know how to display this duration onto the webpage or somewhere I can gather such duration? Please advise. Tq.

Answer (score -3):

You can see it in the internet browsers (F12) or if you use POSTMAN, it show the time.
In also you can use standard python library `time` for measuring the execution time of a piece of code.

Comment: You should provide a minimal example of the approach you are suggesting. Its not very helpful like this.