# How to log Django request time?

Tags: python, django, time, request

How to display Django requests time in my console? For exemple: "GET /cities/ HTTP/1.1", I need time of this response.

Comment: The time of the request, or the time to complete?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can you calculate execution time of a view in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62522117/how-can-you-calculate-execution-time-of-a-view-in-django) in this example instead of printing you can log  it.

Answer (score 2):

the long term and most scalable solution for your question is writing a middleware:

```
  you can take this middleware as an example if you just want to show the request time
```

**code:**
class RequestTimeMiddleware:

```
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    start_time = time.time()
    response = self.get_response(request)

    processing_time = time.time() - start_time

    self.log_request(request, processing_time)

    return response

@staticmethod
def log_request(request, processing_time):
    print(f"Request to {request.path} took {processing_time:.6f} seconds.")
```

make sure to import time for this .

Answer (score 0):

The question needs more clarity in the terms of request time:

- What is meant by request time? Is it the time of view's complete execution or the complete request cycle time?
- Is the request time needed for only a specific view or all of them?
- Is the time to be stored anywhere or it is meant for console display only?

If you need a long-term/scalable solution, you would need to write Django's Middleware(See this thread for a similar solution [How to calculate response time in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937566/how-to-calculate-response-time-in-django)). You can either use cache or add a custom attribute in request to represent the start time in `process_request` and utilize that value in `process_response` to get the approximate time of the request.